# Dynamically displaying option values using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, dynamic

I'm new to PHP and have created a very basic HTML form. As you can see in my form, the option values are all done by hand (there are more, I just simplified this example). What I want is for these to be generated dynamically using just PHP, so that I would physically have to add every single year etc.

I've done some searching but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm after so thought I'd ask here. From what I gather I need to create a query and echo out the option value somehow, although I'm not sure how to do this.

```
SELECT gameYear from games
```

I'd guess the above would be the correct query as all the form would need is the bookYear from the table?

```
<form id = "gameYear" method="get" action="result.php">
<label> 
    Game Year
    <select name="gameYear">
       <option value="2000">2000</option>
       <option value="2001">2001</option>
       <option value="2002">2002</option>
    </select>
</label>
   <input type = "submit" name="search" value = "Search">
</form>
```

Thanks, any help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id = "gameYear" method="get" action="result.php">
<label> 
Game Year
<select name="gameYear">
<option value=''>--Select Year--</option>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$SqlResult = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT gameYear from games");
while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult))
{
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $Row['gameYear'] ?>"><?php echo $Row['gameYear'] ?></option>
}
?>
</select>
</label>
<input type = "submit" name="search" value = "Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT gameYear from games order by gameYear ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die ("Couldn't perform query $sql <br />".mysql_error()); ?>


<form id="gameYear" method="get" action="result.php">
<label>Game Year
<select name="gameYear">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>                        
<option value="<?php echo $row['gameYear'] ?>"><?php echo $row['gameYear']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</label>
<input type = "submit" name="search" value = "Search">
</form>
```

Comment: You may also want to add `ORDER BY gameYear ASC`. Also your `<option value="<?php echo $row['gameYear'] ?>"><?php echo $row['fullname']?></option>` should be <option value="<?php echo $row['gameYear'] ?>"><?php echo $row['gameYear']?></option>